# Swift code "captureOutput()" method not detecting faces

Tags: ios, swift, face-detection

Please tell me if there is any mistakes I have done in this code.

```
  faceDetectorOptions  = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyLow]
    faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: faceDetectorOptions )

    let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    let attachments : CFDictionaryRef  = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate))!
    let ciImage     : CIImage   = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: attachments as? [String : AnyObject])


     let imageOptions = [CIDetectorSmile : true, CIDetectorEyeBlink : true , CIDetectorImageOrientation : 6 ]
    let features = faceDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage, options: imageOptions)
```

I couldn't detect any faces, It should probably work. 
Any suggestions will be appreciated !